# Why does Swagger ignore SwaggerRequestExample in my Asp.NetCore API service definition?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

I am using Swagger (`Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`) to implement an ASP.NET Core Web API service.

I would like to create examples to be consumed/used by service calls from the Swagger UI.

```
public class OwnerCreateExample : IExamplesProvider<Owner>
{
    public Owner GetExamples()
    {
        return new Owner()
        {
            FirstName = "Joe",
            LastName = "Smith",
        };
    }
}
```

I have the following Controller API call definition:

```
[HttpPost]
[SwaggerRequestExample(typeof(Owner), typeof(OwnerCreateExample))]
[Route("Create")]
public void Create(Owner p_Owner)
{
    using (Scope scope = AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(_container))
    {
        var dbContext = _container.GetInstance<FooContext>();
        dbContext.Owners.Add(p_Owner);
        dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

The app compiles and runs, but Swagger seems to ignore the SwaggerRequestExample setting.

The example is not displayed in the UI, nor is it produced as the default parameter.

I know I can tag the individual fields in the class definitions via XML comments.
I would rather not go that route as I have many class/fields in my object model.

Am I missing some additional configuration in my services initialization at startup?

Comment: did you try [this](https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters/issues/83#issuecomment-459079278)?

Comment: @Andy:  Thx! Spot on! Now things work as advertised.